Testing Kubernetes on baremetal Almalinux, when I try to add nodes I get: found multiple CRI endpoints on the host
I am attempting to create a kubernetes cluster.
I got 3 pc with Almalinux 9.
When I give the command
kubeadm join MASTER_NODE_IP:6443 --token TOKEN    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:HASH --v=5

I get
I1224 time   15683 join.go:421] [preflight] found NodeName empty; using OS hostname as NodeName
found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.detectCRISocketImpl
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:262
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.DetectCRISocket
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:270
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.SetNodeRegistrationDynamicDefaults
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/initconfiguration.go:119
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.SetJoinDynamicDefaults
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/joinconfiguration.go:42
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.DefaultedJoinConfiguration
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/joinconfiguration.go:158
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.LoadOrDefaultJoinConfiguration
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/joinconfiguration.go:73
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newJoinData
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/join.go:438
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdJoin.func2
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/join.go:237
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).InitData
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:185
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdJoin.func1
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/join.go:175
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:985
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:1117
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:1041
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:47
main.main
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:272
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1700

What should be the best approach to fix this error?
